# Is it possible to combine console.timeEnd() and console.debug()?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I would like to measure time in browser javascript.

I use console.log(), console.debug() ...etc.

But console.timeEnd() behavior is similar to console.log(). It's wrote to console in case of "log" switch is on in browser's JS-Console.
I need to write time to console only if debug messages has switched on in browser.

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing [built in](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/) that will do that for you, but it's very easy to implement it yourself: Maintain a `Map` of labels to start times, and use `Date.now()` or `performance.now()` to get the start and end times.

Very roughly:

```
const debugTimeMap = new Map();
const debugTime = label => {
    if (debugTimeMap.has(label)) {
        console.warn(`Timer '${label}' already exists`);
    } else {
        debugTimeMap.set(label, Date.now());
    }
};
const debugTimeEnd = label => {
    const start = debugTimeMap.get(label);
    if (start === undefined) {
        console.warn(`Invalid debugTime label "${label}"`);
    } else {
        debugTimeMap.delete(label);
        console.debug(`${label}: ${Date.now() - start} ms`);
    }
};
```

```js
const debugTimeMap = new Map();
const debugTime = label => {
    if (debugTimeMap.has(label)) {
        console.warn(`Timer '${label}' already exists`);
    } else {
        debugTimeMap.set(label, Date.now());
    }
};
const debugTimeEnd = label => {
    const start = debugTimeMap.get(label);
    if (start === undefined) {
        console.warn(`Invalid debugTime label "${label}"`);
    } else {
        debugTimeMap.delete(label);
        console.debug(`${label}: ${Date.now() - start} ms`);
    }
};

debugTime("x");
setTimeout(() => {
    debugTimeEnd("x");
}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
```

```html
(Look in the real console, and don't forget to turn on debug output in the console.)
```